# Save the email HTML in Laravel

Tags: laravel, html-email

I'm building an application to create email templates and send emails. I want to keep a log of the emails sent out, specially the actual email html. The reason being the email template might change in the future so we need to know exactly what text we've sent out on a particular email.

I'm using Laravel 7 and I know I have to do this on MessageSending or MessageSent event.

```
protected $listen = [
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSendingMessage',
    ],
    'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSent' => [
        'App\Listeners\LogSentMessage',
    ],
];
```

Anyone has done something similar before?

Comment: No, But what's the problem?

Comment: @mohammad.kaab, did you read the question? I want to save the email html in the db/ as a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can view body of the mail by accessing message property of MessageSending or MessageSent event. Bellow is a sample code that you could add to your listener.

```php
/**
 * @param \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending $event
 */
public function handle(MessageSending $event): void
{
    $messageBody = $event->message->getBody();

    // Store this message to S3, DB or some other file storage...
    // ...
}
```